# Pythonic conversion of single item list to string

Tags: python, performance, lxml

I am curious on what an efficient/pythonic implementation would be for converting a single item list to a string.  I am working with the `lxml` api, specifically `xpath` which returns a `list` of `Element`s.

Assuming I have the following xml

```
<Root>
  <Name>MyName</Name>
  <Comment>MyComment</Comment>
  <Details>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </Details>
</Root>
```

Now I want to retrieve the value of `a = xpath('Comment/text()')` (assuming the context node is `Root`).  I can use one of the following.

```
strExample = a[0]
```

or

```
strExample = ''.join(a)
```

I assume the former would be (trivially) more efficient.  Is one or the other, or some alternative, the preferred approach in regards to readability and efficiency.

Comment: Yes, `a[0]` is definitely going to be more efficient. It also seems conceptually much more obvious: taking the first string out of a list by taking the first string out of a list makes more sense than doing it by joining all of the strings on the assumption that there's exactly one. And it's more robust, in that if your assumptions are violated you don't silently get something that looks right but isn't in as many cases. So, I'd say the One Obvious Way To Do It is `a[0]`.

Comment: (Although, if you're even more worried about robustness or making your assumptions explicit, adding a check for `if len(a) != 1: raise SomeException` and then doing `strExample = a[0]` might be TOOWTDI…)

Comment: Thanks @abarnert, I wasn't sure if there was some single item list to string method that encapsulates the length checking.  When using xpath it seems a bit messy to have all of my xpath expressions ending in [0].  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Without knowing that your XML schema doesn't allow multiple `Comment` tags under a `Root`, XPath `Comment/text()` pretty much has to return a list. If it returned a string for a single `Comment` tag, but a list of strings for multiple comment tags (and an empty list for 0 comment tags?), that would make the code to deal with XPath results a lot messier in general, even if it would be a bit less messy here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since one of your qualifications was performance, let's start by testing that:

```
In [314]: %timeit a[0]
39.4 ns ± 1.38 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)    
In [315]: %timeit ''.join(a)
81 ns ± 3.68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [316]: a = ['My Comment' * 100000]    
In [317]: %timeit a[0]
39.2 ns ± 0.696 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
In [318]: %timeit ''.join(a)
81.4 ns ± 2.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

So, as a rough guess, `a[0]` is about twice as fast, and that's a constant difference, not depending on the length of the string.

Of course that *could* conceivably be something CPython-specific, or CPython 3.6-specific… both if you think about it, while it's possible that `''.join(a)` could be linear without some optimization for single values, it's hard to imagine that `a[0]` could be.

---

Next, which is more readable? Well, conceptually, what you're trying to do is get the first and only value out of the list.

- `a[0]` gets the first value out of the list, which is obviously the same thing under the assumption that there's only one.
- `''.join(a)` gets all of the values out of the list, concatenated together. You can pretty easily prove it's the same thing under the assumptions that there's only one and it's a string, but it's not as immediately obvious.

---

The other potential concern is robustness.

The element not being found, and `a` therefore being empty, seems like a plausible possibility. In that case, `a[0]` will raise an `IndexError`, while `''.join(a)` will silently return an empty string.

Multiple elements being found seems like something that should never happen. If it does, `a[0]` will return the first one, which may still be useful, while `''.join(a)` will silently join them all together into nonsense, which almost certainly won't be. (Although if that *could* happen, and your code isn't prepared to deal with it, you might be better adding an explicit `if len(a) != 1: raise SomeException(…)` test than relying on either.)

---

Putting this all together, I think `a[0]` is The One Obvious Way To Do It (unless you need the robustness against multiple values, in which case an explicit test, and then `a[0]`, is TOOWTDI).